# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object MotionController.FixedUpdate

Tags: c#, unity3d

Eu estou a seguir este tutorial do unity: http://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/2d-controllers

Isto estava a correr bem até à parte onde se faz o teste para ver se estou a tocar no chão ou não.
Depois de fazer a verificação e tentar correr o projecto apareceu este erro:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   MotionController.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/MotionController.cs:40)

O código está muito idêntico ao do tutorial:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MotionController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float maxSpeed = 10f;                                                //Velocidade maxima do boneco

    //    public float jetpackForce = 75.0f;
    //    public float forwardMovementSpeed = 0.5f;

    private Animator anim;

    private bool grounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    float groundRadius = 0.2f;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    public float jumpForce = 700f;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //START TUTORIAL
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        //END TUROTIAL
        groundCheck = transform.Find("groundCheck");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
//  void Update () {
//        if(grounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
//        {
//            anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
//            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
//        }
//    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
        anim.SetBool("Ground", grounded);

        //START TUTORIAL -- ANDAR
        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
        //END TUTORIAL


        bool jetpackActive = Input.GetButton("Fire1");

        if (jetpackActive)
        {
//            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jetpackForce));
        }
//        Vector2 newVelocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
//        newVelocity.x = forwardMovementSpeed;
//        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = newVelocity;
    }
 }
```

O erro é sinalizado nesta função: `grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);`

Se eu apagar a linha acima, o projecto já funciona, mas não faz o pretendido

Agora o projecto não faz nada por causa do erro listado em cima.
Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Você chama o método `Start()` antes de chamar o `FixedUpdate()`?

Comment: É a primeira vez que tou a mexer no unity e tou a seguir o tutorial. No video não se chamou o método Start() em lado nenhum.

Comment: Mas a variável está nula nesse ponto, você deve ter esquecido algo ou o tutorial está errado.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a variável `groundCheck` não está sendo inicializada, por isso o `NullReferenceException`

Essa variável está sendo inicializada dentro do método `Start()`, porém, como você disse nos comentários, você não está chamando o método `Start()`.

Ou você esqueceu de chamar de este método ou a variável deve ser instanciada em outro lugar.